# Doobie batch update using generics

Tags: scala, generics, doobie

Can you make [batch update](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/07-Updating.html#batch-updates) in doobie with generic types?

This code:

```
def insertMany[T](ps: List[T]): Task[List[T]] = {
  val sql = "insert into person (name, age) values (?, ?)"
  Update[T](sql).updateMany(ps)
}
```

gives me: `could not find implicit value for parameter W: doobie.util.Write[T]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, here how it would look like:

```
import doobie.implicits._
import doobie._
import monix.eval.Task
import cats.data.NonEmptyList

def insertMany[T: Write](ps: NonEmptyList[T]): ConnectionIO[Int] = {
  val sql = "insert into person (name, age) values (?, ?)"
  Update[T](sql).updateMany(ps)
}


println(insertMany(NonEmptyList.of[String]("aa", "bb")))
```

> The answer is based on gitter conversion with @J0kerPanda